# Связь ManyToOne и OneToMany

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

Немного не понимаю, правильно ли сделал связь между таблицами. Есть 2 сущности, город и дом. В одном городе может быть много домов, а дом присвоен к одному городу. Получается связь от дома к городу OneToMany, а от города к дому ManyToOne. Самое основное: по какому атрибуты их соединять, чтобы было корректно? Потому что мне кажется, что я что-то лишнее написал, тот же city_id и house_id, наверное, не должны содержаться в House.

Дом

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "house", schema = "public")
public class House {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "house")
    private Set<Contract> contract;

    @Column(name = "id_landlord", nullable = false)
    private Long id_landlord;
    @Column(name = "outside", nullable = false)
    private String outside;
    @Column(name = "rooms", nullable = false)
    private Integer rooms;
    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private Double price;
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    getter,setter...

}
```

Город

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "city", schema = "public")
public class City {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.REFRESH
})
@JoinColumn(name = "house_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Set<House> house;

@Column(name = "id_region", nullable = false)
private Integer id_region;
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

getter,setter...

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка найдена, неправильно построил связи между House и City, это видно по синим ключам на скриншоте, верхний правильный, а нижний - нет:

House:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;
```

City:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.REFRESH
    }, mappedBy = "city")
    private Set<House> house;
```